# How to blur an image by opencv in C?

Tags: c, opencv

I'm using opencv in C for a project of mine, and I need to blur an image.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
/*
Function displays the blurred image of the frame
Input: frame
Output: none
*/
void blurImage(link_t* frame)
{
    IplImage* imageSrc = cvLoadImage(frame->frame->path, 1); // frame->frame->path is the path of the image
    int i = 0;
    if (!imageSrc)//The image is empty.
    {
        printf("could not open or find image");
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 1; i < 51; i += 2)
        {
            blur(imageSrc, imageSrc, Size(i, i)); // Not compiling - LNK error
        }
        cvShowImage("Display window", imageSrc); //display the blurred image
    }
}
```

I've read a lot online about this and all the answers I'm finding are at c++/python so they aren't helping me.

Comment: I don't think blur() exists in C, you probably have to write it yourself...

Comment: Your comment in the code is `not working`.  Define `not working`.  Also, since opencv is open source, why not get the `c++` source, find the blur function and port it to `c`?

Comment: Can you please send a link to how to write it? @gdelab

Comment: @KevinDTimm by not working I mean not compiling - a LNK error. I'll edit my post.

Comment: You could use [`cvFilter2D`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d) -- see the [OpenCV Image Smoothing tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks @DanMašek I read about it and figured out how to do blur!

Comment: The equivalent of [`cv::blur`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=blur#blur) in C interface is [`cvSmooth`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#smooth) with `CV_BLUR` as 3rd parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Since blur() doesn't exist in C (only in C++ or Python) I used `cvPyrDown` and `cvPyrUp`.

Using down function and then up the image got the effect of blur (like decreasing size of image what downsize the resolution save it and then resize it to normal).

How to use cvPyrDown [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=cvpyrdown+example&source=bl&ots=hTM8cgjGNb&sig=a7SeA2ZkEP96RCsDXd0D-_knIgM&hl=iw&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9p6r9ueLUAhWJmbQKHa49A3kQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=cvpyrdown%20example&f=false).

The code:

```
void blurImage(void)
{
    IplImage* imageSrc = cvLoadImage("<Image path>", 1);
    IplImage* imageDst;
    if (!imageSrc)//The image is empty.
    {
        printf("could not open or find image");
    }
    else
    {
        imageDst = cvCreateImage(cvSize(imageSrc->width/2,imageSrc->height/2), imageSrc->depth, imageSrc->nChannels);
        cvPyrDown(imageSrc, imageDst, CV_GAUSSIAN_5x5); //Down size
        cvPyrUp(imageDst, imageSrc, CV_GAUSSIAN_5x5); // Up size
        cvShowImage("Display window", imageSrc); // Display the blurred image
        cvWaitKey(1000); // Wait for 1000 milliseconds
        cvReleaseImage(&imageDst);
        cvReleaseImage(&imageSrc);
    }
}
```